# Angular 2 require JSON is empty

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular 2 I created a directive, when I require a JSON file, the object is `empty`, and it is looking for the file `test.json.js`:

```
var tests = require('./test.json');

@Directive({
    selector: 'textarea[test]'
})

export class Test {

...
```

Comment: Try to check by changing file name to `test.json`. if not worked share whats inside `test.json.js` ?

Comment: I have change it to test.json.js, the object is empty.

Comment: And you do realize your variable is called tests but you are using test in textarea[]?

Comment: Are you using Webpack or SystemJs as the module loader?

Comment: Not webpack, It is SystemJs

Comment: Did you install json plugin? https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-json

Comment: No I did not install.

Comment: After install the plugin-json, how can I use it?